# How can I display the subjects of the student when student logged in

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This is the student who have a subject of National Service Training Program 1 and Physical Education 1
here is the code and picture

```
select en.*, su.descc from enrollment en inner join subject su on su.year = en.year
```

[This is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nw5OJ.png)

after that when the student logged in it only shows National Service Training Program 1 subject, how to display also the Physical Education 1?

[This is the result when the student logged in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9wyx.png)

```
  <?php
session_start();
include_once("config.php");

if(!isset($_SESSION['sid'])){
            header("Location:index.php");
    }   
       // Subject
        $i=$_SESSION['sid'];
        $q=mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT en.*, su.descc FROM enrollment en INNER JOIN subject su ON 
        su.year = en.year
         WHERE id='$i'") or die (mysqli_error());
        $r=mysqli_fetch_array($q);

?>
<html>
         <body>
                   <h2> Subject: <?php echo $r['descc'];?> </h2>
                    <h2> Subject: <?php echo $r['descc'];?> </h2>
         </body>
</html>
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**
This would be the Expected output when the student logged in
[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKmDn.png)

Comment: you need a loop (e.g while loop)

Comment: @KenLee while ($res=mysqli_fetch_array($rs)) like this??

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Comment: You have an error. [`mysqli_error()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) needs one argument. Please consider switching error mode on instead. [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need a loop (e.g while loop).

Please change your codes (for the body part) to

```
<body>
<?php while ($r=mysqli_fetch_array($q)){ ?>
                   <h2> Subject: <?php echo $r['descc'];?> </h2>

<?php } ?>

         </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please see about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries